# Inflating a compressed byte array in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to port the following piece of code to a WinRT app:

```
using (var stream = new InflaterInputStream(new MemoryStream(compressedBytes)))
{
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] writeData = new byte[4096];
    int resLen;
    while ((resLen = stream.Read(writeData, 0, writeData.Length)) > 0)
    {
        memory.Write(writeData, 0, resLen);
    }
    uncompressedBytes = memory.ToArray();
}
```

I'm using SharpZipLib for its `InflaterInputStream` class, but there is no WinRT compilation available (recompiling it myself is also not an option, due to the differences between .NET/WinRT being too large).

Anyone have any suggestions as to what native/3rd party functionality I can use to achieve the same result?

Comment: The only way to use SharpZipLib within a Modern UI application is to compile it against the .NET Framework WinRT profile.  So you can either create your own mini-library or recompile the entire library your choice.

Comment: Zip support was added to .NET 4.5, I suppose you'll want to use System.IO.Compression.GZipStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Hans Passant's comment I figured out that using the following line yields the same result as using the InflaterInputStream:

```
using (DeflateStream stream = new DeflateStream(new MemoryStream(compressedBytes, 2, compressedBytes.Length - 2), CompressionMode.Decompress))
```

The reason for skipping the first two bytes is that they are part of the zlib spec and not the deflate spec: http://george.chiramattel.com/blog/2007/09/deflatestream-block-length-does-not-match.html